# Is there a GUI utility to mount remote filesystems over SSH?

Tags: ssh, gui, sshfs

Is there a GUI utility to mount remote filesystems over SSH (SSHFS)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you are strictly bound to using sshfs, but by default the GVFS in GNOME supports SSH connections. In the file manager go to File -> Connect to server:

[image]

This will mount the remote SSH server in a folder you can access from the file manager. If you need to access the mount in the command line it's in .gvfs.

You can also mount it in Nautilus. Just hit CTRL+L and in the address bar type: `ssh://server-ip/somepath/`

- [Where is "Connect to Server" for ssh connections in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34768/where-is-connect-to-server-for-ssh-connections-in-unity)

Comment: You can also mount it in Nautilus. Just hit CTRL+L and in the address bar type: ssh://server-ip/somepath/

Comment: @JavierRivera I've read about that's only a wrapping on the file explorer.
It's not the same than real filesystem integration. SSHFS is just what really works for that. But im not sure about GVFS. I will check it, thanks.

Comment: This apparently connects as SFTP with no option for SSH in Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 4):

#### Gigolo

Gigolo is a front-end to easily manage connections to remote filesystems using GIO/GVfs. It allows you to quickly connect/mount a remote filesystem and manage bookmarks of such.

To install Gigolo in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gigolo
```

Comment: This is not the answer since the software you mentioned only do sftp and does not mount sshfs. (I don't downvote, but technically you have not answered the question)

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to access the remote filesystem, you should be able to go to sftp://hostname.example.com in your file browser without having to mount it.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus can do it:
File-->Connect to a server

Comment: This is not a ssh filesystem integration. The goal of the sshfs is that you can access files with the usual way, ie: /myserver and not ssh://blablabla.