# Where is "Connect to Server" for ssh connections in Unity?

Tags: unity, nautilus, ssh

Cannot find "connect to server" in 11.04, looks like unity doesn't have it. Is there other very similar way to connect to another Ubuntu computer via SSH? (not in terminal)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you click on the nautilus icon (the folder with the house on it) it will launch the file manager. "Connect to Server" is in the file menu.

[image]

In Ubuntu 12.10 you need to install the following package (click to install):

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: In 12.10, connect to server gives error if this package is not installed: `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1050138`

Answer (score 8):

### Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `nautilus-connect-server`

[image]

Or with Nautilus open of by selecting your desktop, go to *File* > *Connect to Server*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open a **Nautilus** window: it should be in the **File menu**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click on the desktop, the move the mouse to the top panel, in menu choose file, connect to server.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [HotSSH](http://projects.gnome.org/hotssh//index.html), a GUI for starting and managing SSH sessions.  You can install it from the Unity application menu.
[image]

Comment: in ubuntu 10.10 i was able to go Places-> Connect to server  and it actually opens remote computer in Nautilus. I use it to share files between my laptop and desktop, it very convenient because i can see whole file system. I'm not much in networking (may be the way i did it kind of wrong or something), but I just found a way to do what i need and used it.

Comment: Oh, you want to get at the files on the other computer.  Normally when people say "ssh connection" they mean to open a shell on the other machine, which is what this does.  In that case [Jorge's answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34768/where-is-connect-to-server-for-ssh-connections-in-unity/34771#34771) is better.

Comment: @poolie, Eugene is referring to sftp, i.e. ssh+ftp, which allows file browsing over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your desktop and select "Connect to the server" from the File menu.

Answer (score 0):

The option "connect to  server" is not where is used to be on nautilus. Instead, you should go to the desktop, point with your mouse at the upper edge -- this will bring up a menu where you choose >file>connect to server.