# Does 11.10 have 'Connect to Server' option

Tags: 11.10, networking, samba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is “Connect to Server” for ssh connections in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34768/where-is-connect-to-server-for-ssh-connections-in-unity)

Does Ubuntu 11.10 have 'Connect to Server' option as in 10.10 and earlier?
Like earlier versions, it does not recognize my NAS unit.
The earlier versions from 9.04 on needed the samba and nsswitch configuration files editing before they would see the NAS unit but would connect from 'Connect to Server' under the places menu but this option is missing in 11.10 (I have skipped 11.04).