# Access media between two Ubuntu-based systems sharing in Samba

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, xubuntu

I have a laptop and desktop running Ubuntu and Xubuntu respectively -- both are 64 bit 11.10 version.

I use XBMC on both machines to play media.

I want to access the media on my desktop and play it on my laptop.

I need somthing that can enable Library Update [tried UPnP and I have to find the directory everytime].

I tried many things, but on either machine the other machine won't show up on the Windows network or auto detect.

Manually adding the IP address opens a password dialog and I can't even access with the id and pass of that machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SSH for file sharing like described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/34771/37157 It's a lot easier than Samba.

Comment: the files i'm accessing are stored in a NTFS partition

Answer (score 0):

Steps need to do
1. check both computer can ping each other. ping from A computer with B computer's ip

```
ping BcomputerIP  [from A machine and vice versa]
```

1. Try to share your file using samba in right way. See here http://shantanucse.blogspot.com/2012/01/share-your-file-with-windows-using.html

Comment: works pings

the files i'm accessing are stored in a NTFS partition

Comment: 1. Did you share any folder in home directory? if yes, then maybe you did not set write permission on NTFS partition(not samba problem). Set your NTFS partition write permission http://askubuntu.com/questions/77655/how-do-i-enable-ntfs-write-support [follow the last answer].

Comment: check guest account (no need password) in samba share option.

Answer (score 0):

SMB protocol is used for sharing between windows and Linux. For Linux to Linux folder sharing you can SSH protocol

Comment: how do i accesss using ssh in XBMC media sharing

Comment: the files i'm accessing are stored in a NTFS partition

Comment: i dont know much xmbc.if u want ntfs then u try this