# Mount drive on remote machine

Tags: 12.04, mount

My current set up is:

- I have my main machine (Darkseid) upstairs which has a drive with all my films on it, which I don't keep mounted.
- Downstairs, next to the tv, I have a htpc (Archangel) which has xbmc installed on it, which points to a samba share on the main machine.

Everything works fine when the drive is mounted, but is there a script I can write to send a command to the upstairs machine from the downstairs machine to mount the drive to save the walk upstairs? #lazy

Both machines are Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be to establish a remote connection to your server upstairs by using [**SSH**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH).

By this you are able to remotely mount or unmount drives and you can even mount a remote directory on your local mythubuntu machine.

Related questions:

- [How to use SSH (ssh & rsync commands)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58539/how-to-use-ssh-ssh-rsync-commands)
- [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)
- [Is there a GUI utility to mount remote filesystems over SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4625/is-there-a-gui-utility-to-mount-remote-filesystems-over-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

Not a script, but you can do something on boot for your machine, I did this on my server this morning, nothing wrong with a bit of laziness :)

[AutomaticallyMountPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)

Once you have worked out the terminal command to mount the drive;

- Open Start-up applications (search start-up in dash/click top right > Start-up Applications)
- Click Add
- Name is Whatever you want
- Command is the command you used in terminal (CTRL SHIFT C to copy)

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I think I missed a vital bit out of my Q, I want to be able to ask the upstairs machine to mount the film drive whilst on the downstairs machine.